# How to do animation to wordpress site like puzzle?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is on wordpress exist any plugin for this javascript(https://www.canva.com/) so on mouse moving shows whats behind, how is it called anyway? Thx

Comment: Asking for advice is off topic in Stack Overflow, refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Its something that I dont know, not advice lol